# Mesh to obstacle deformation

Tags: game-physics

I was wondering if there was some starting resource in order to understand and work through this kind of situation and problem. Let's say I have a drop of water in my game which I can control. I then hit a sharp edge and now my water splits into two pieces. If I somehow get my water to touch the other piece, then my meshes will dynamic combine back to the scale of the original. Thus, maybe I am searching for how to dynamically destruct and reconstruct a mesh based on what I am hitting. If I keep doing this over and over, I get more pieces coming off. What exactly do I need to search for and where can I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is usually very expensive and not trivial to implement. What you're looking for is [soft-body dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_body_dynamics).

I'm not sure if you're asking specifically about fluids, but if you are, you should take a look to [Smoothed-Particle Hydrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics). Even if you don't need the actual accurate hydrodynamics some implementations will help you burrow some ideas.